# Where can I find documentation for Django?

Tags: django

Here is a site with documentation for various Bash functions in a format that I am used to:

http://ss64.com/bash/

MSDN has something similar for C#. There is something similar for Autohotkey, and so on.

But I haven't found anything analogous for Django. Whenever I google for anything about Django I have a hard time reaching an answer. For example I wanted to understand what INTERNAL_IPS means and googled for it:

https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what+is+django+INTERNAL_IPS

I clicked the top hits but none of them says what INTERNAL_IPS does. I would like to find a reference site that tells me a bit about what INTERNAL_IPS does and what types of values I can give it.

Does a Django reference site like this exist?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#internal-ips

Comment: Or simply https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ and use the freaking search field...

Comment: In that google search the first link will lead you there.. What so difficult ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: That's exactly my problem with the Django documentation. That paragraph doesn't say anything about what INTERNAL_IPS does.

Comment: Django tries to maintain a high standard of documentation, but it's not perfect. When you see something that is poorly documented, please take a few minutes to create a ticket on http://code.djangoproject.com/newticket, like I did for `INTERNAL_IPS` ([#25710](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25710)).

Comment: Thanks @knbk: I'll take time to do that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/files/file/

You can also visit Django on Github for more links to documentation:

https://github.com/django/django

just scroll to the bottom of the Github page.